# looping through calculator button in js

Tags: javascript

Hello I am currently new at javascript and having some problem understanding the actual work of for loop in a calculator. I want to know why we are looping through buttons and how javascript is working behind the scenes.

Here is the code i am struggling with:

```js
let keypadBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".op-btn");
    
for(let i = 0; i < keypadBtn.length; i++){
  keypadBtn[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(keypadBtn[i].getAttribute("data-num"));
  })
  }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
      <div class="op-btn btn-yellow" data-num = "*">*</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-yellow" data-num = "/">/</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-yellow" data-num = "-">-</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-yellow" data-num = "+">+</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = ".">.</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "9">9</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "8">8</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "7">7</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "6">6</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "5">5</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "4">4</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "3">3</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "2">2</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "1">1</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-white" data-num = "0">0</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-green">=</div>
      <div class="op-btn btn-red">C</div>
</div>
```

Actually I know how the code will work the problem is i want to know 
how the for loop is able to get the exact button value by looping and
not any other value, as variable "i" keep on increasing by value 1.
if "i" is increasing how it is able to exactly index my button ? 
Well Thanks in advance

Comment: You're iterating over the list of buttons so you can listen to click event. It's one thing to display the calculator but to interact with it when you press something you're expecting javascript to do something that's what the addEventListener does.

Comment: Learn to use map() over for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble with iteration in general **which** this is, I would leave you to these tutorials : [Array Iteration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Urwzk6ILvPQ), [Iteration In General](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cGoFfXJxsM).

Now for an explanation on what your code does.

```
let keypadBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.op-btn') // Grabs all elements containing this the `.op-btn` class

for (let i = 0; i < keypadBtn.length; i++) { // Initializing the for loop
     keypadBtn[i].addEventListener('click', () => { // Attach the click event to each of the buttons
        // Once click this `console.log` will fire printing 
        // the element you clicked to browser console
        console.log(keypadBtn[i].getAttribute('data-num')) 
     })
}
```

Comment: Actually I know how the code will work the problem is i want to know how the for loop is able to get the exact button value by looping and not any other value, as variable "i" keep on increasing by value 1.if "i" is increasing how it is able to exactly index my button ? 
Well Thanks in advance

Comment: you get a list of button index from 0 to the Number of buttons and take one button at  a time and attach click event to it.

Comment: Well as I mentioned this mainly **iteration**. **iterating** basically going through each element/index inside of the `iterator`, The video **Iteration In General** I provided in the answer covers this in more detail. And if you're wondering how `i` knows if it's the correct button or not... ***well it doesn't***... `i` is just a number ranging from 0 to `keypadBtn.length`, `keypadBtn` is a `NodeList` containing the buttons (An NodeList is an Array like type fyi), knowing this you can do `keypadBtn[0]` and it will return the first button, `keypadBtn[1]` second, `keypadBtn[2]` third, etc...

Comment: What i actually understand is this (Correct me if i am wrong) - The for loop is writing my code the number of times the button is actually there. And then executing the specific index button code when i press that button.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote above add the click event to all buttons. The loop here is to traverse each button(div). Read comments below:

```
 let keypadBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".op-btn"); //Select all divs. It picks all the items with class name .opt-btn

    for(let i = 0; i < keypadBtn.length; i++){ 
        keypadBtn[i].addEventListener("click",function(){ //attach click event to each button
            console.log(keypadBtn[i].getAttribute("data-num")); // you can get the values here and based on it you can calculate the result
         })
    }
```